# How can I use the image that I browse from SD card and after How can I make it gray or invered?

Tags: java, android-intent, image-processing, android-imageview

```
public class ImageProcActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnBrowser, btnOriginal, btnGray, btnInvert;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
    static final int ActID =1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_proc);

        btnBrowser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery);
        btnOriginal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_original);
        btnGray = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_gray);
        btnInvert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_invert);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        ImageView image;

        btnBrowser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentIG = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intentIG.setType("image/*");
                ImageProcActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intentIG, ActID);
            }

        });
        btnOriginal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v){
                //iv.setImageURI(onActivityResult.uri);
                //iv.setImageURI(OnActivityResultListener(intentIG,ActID));
```

//I don't know how to use the image from Browser here. can't define as a variable... how can I get it?

```
            }
        });



        btnGray.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

//And also How can I make the image gray? I researched several codes but don't understand. could you explain in easy way I just strated to study JAVA few weeks ago...

```
            }
        });

        btnInvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int activityID, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if(activityID==ActID && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            tv.setText(uri.toString());
            iv.setImageURI(uri);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new here so you faced some issue in formatting your question.

By the way, you can use below code snippet for converting image to greyscale, let me know if you have any further confusion :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GrayScale {
   BufferedImage  image;
   int width;
   int height;
   public GrayScale() {
      try {
         File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
         image = ImageIO.read(input);
         width = image.getWidth();
         height = image.getHeight();
         for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
               Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
               int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299);
               int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587);
               int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114);
               Color newColor = new Color(red+green+blue,
               red+green+blue,red+green+blue);
               image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
               }
          }
         File ouptut = new File("grayscale.jpg");
         ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);
      } catch (Exception e) {}
   }
   static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
   {
      GrayScale obj = new GrayScale();
   }
}
```